# Rstudio error with the fviz_nbclust() function

Tags: r, cluster-analysis, static-analysis, factoextra

I'm doing a report for a data analysis and statistical learning subject.
The problem is in the clustering phase. I have to find the optimal number of clusters, and i already done. But when i try to display the graph with the following function it gives me an error:

```
nb<-NbClust(df, diss=NULL,distance="euclidean",method="average")

fviz_nbclust(nb)
```

> Error in if (class(best_nc) == "numeric") print(best_nc) else if (class(best_nc) ==  :
> the condition has length > 1

df is the standardized data set with only numerical data.
The error is referred to the `fviz_nbclust` function.
I'd like to know what to do. I have already try to reinstall the packages, RStudio, everything but nothing. I also did, inside the `NbClust()` function the `min_nc` or `max_nc` and stuff like that.

Thanks for your help.

```r
> dput(df)
structure(c(-1.04227826822844, -0.171114188130418, -0.804688064565345, 
1.37322213567972, 1.09603356473944, -0.042419494479573, 0.85844336107634, 
-0.844286431842528, 1.53161560478845, 1.70980825753577, -0.844286431842528, 
0.155572341906342, -0.636395003637318, -1.04227826822844, 0.363463770111553, 
0.353564178292257, 1.86820172664451, 1.55141478842704, -0.715591738191684, 
-0.824487248203937, 0.60105397377465, -0.299808881781262, 0.660451524690425, 
1.37322213567972, -0.745290513649571, 1.23462785020958, -0.804688064565345, 
-0.181013779949713, -0.685892962733796, 0.373363361930848, -0.487901126347882, 
0.403062137388736, 1.32372417658324, -0.883884799119711, -0.903683982758303, 
0.234769076460708, -0.270110106323375, 0.521857239220284, -1.04227826822844, 
-0.299808881781262, -0.963081533674077, 0.422861321027327, 1.22472825839028, 
-0.131515820853235, 0.848543769257044, 2.52157478671803, -1.04227826822844, 
-0.735390921830275, 1.16533070747451, -0.903683982758303, -0.53739908544436, 
0.85844336107634, 0.551556014678172, -0.992780309131965, -0.53739908544436, 
-0.14141541267253, -0.873985207300416, 1.16533070747451, -0.854186023661824, 
-0.289909289961967, 1.55141478842704, 0.205070301002821, 2.38298050124788, 
-0.972981125493373, -0.53739908544436, 2.37308090942859, -0.745290513649571, 
0.264467851918595, 0.917840911992114, -0.527499493625065, -0.963081533674077, 
-0.774989289107458, -0.131515820853235, -1.04227826822844, -0.369106024516333, 
1.26432662566747, 1.25442703384817, -0.963081533674077, -1.00267990095126, 
-1.04227826822844, -0.963081533674077, 2.04639437939183, -0.428503575432107, 
-0.210712555407601, -0.240411330865488, -0.289909289961967, -0.992780309131965, 
0.175371525544933, -0.478001534528586, -0.844286431842528, -1.04227826822844, 
-0.745290513649571, -0.438403167251403, 1.72960744117437, -0.854186023661824, 
-0.240411330865488, -0.86408561548112, -1.04227826822844, 2.3433821339707, 
1.28412580930606, -0.79478847274605, -0.972981125493373, -0.923483166396894, 
-1.04227826822844, -1.00267990095126, 0.422861321027327, -1.04227826822844, 
-1.04227826822844, -0.082017861756756, 1.30392499294465, -0.438403167251403, 
-1.04227826822844, -0.289909289961967, -0.745290513649571, -0.93338275821619, 
-0.586897044540839, -1.00267990095126, 2.67006866400746, -0.567097860902248, 
-1.00267990095126, 1.43261968659549, 0.957439279269297, -0.280009698142671, 
-1.02247908458985, -0.636395003637318, 0.808945401979861, 0.620853157413242, 
-0.834386840023233, -1.03237867640915, 1.97709723665676, 1.76920580845155, 
-0.616595819998726, 1.05643519746225, 0.561455606497468, -0.349306840877741, 
2.3433821339707, 0.868342952895636, -1.04227826822844, 0.333764994653665, 
0.0268776482554972, 1.8880009102831, 1.39302131931831, -0.626495411818022, 
0.868342952895636, 0.640652341051833, 0.13577315826775, -0.0127207190216858, 
-1.04227826822844, -0.497800718167177, -1.04227826822844, -0.963081533674077, 
1.74940662481296, 0.502058055581693, -0.804688064565345, -0.458202350889994, 
0.888142136534227, 1.62071193116211, -0.497800718167177, -1.04227826822844, 
1.1752302992938, 1.75930621663225, -0.893784390939007, -0.972981125493373, 
0.214969892822116, -0.161214596311122, 0.452560096485214, 0.779246626521974, 
-1.00267990095126, -1.03237867640915, -0.0721182699374602, -0.00282112720239002, 
-1.04227826822844, -0.695792554553092, -0.695792554553092, 0.898041728353523, 
-0.547298677263656, -0.547298677263656, -0.86408561548112, -0.992780309131965, 
-0.60669622817943, 0.987138054727185, -0.893784390939007, 1.11583274837803, 
-0.695792554553092, 1.4128205029569, 0.0862751991712717, -0.804688064565345, 
-0.844286431842528, 2.24438621577774, 0.0466768318940887, -0.992780309131965, 
-0.735390921830275, -0.418603983612811, -0.909759252647386, 0.576794304173131, 
-0.89841151557242, 0.644880726622926, -0.274285976449302, 0.531403355873268, 
-0.637413562848207, 1.11013794669652, -0.104069920324816, -0.0700267090999183, 
-0.399111084273926, 1.07609473547163, -0.206199553999508, -0.909759252647386, 
1.04205152424673, 3.31159893923988, 0.0321029245747737, 0.372535036823747, 
-0.875716041422489, -0.89841151557242, -0.455849769648755, 1.04205152424673, 
-0.523936192098549, 0.724314886147686, -0.89841151557242, 1.93852275316902, 
-0.841672830197591, -0.909759252647386, -0.909759252647386, -0.285633713524268, 
-0.183504079849576, -0.909759252647386, 0.463316933423473, -0.89841151557242, 
-0.909759252647386, 0.486012407573405, 1.25765852867108, -0.0586789720249525, 
-0.887063778497454, -0.909759252647386, 1.96121822731896, 0.066146135799671, 
0.066146135799671, 0.63353298954796, 0.826444519822378, 1.00800831302183, 
-0.909759252647386, -0.887063778497454, -0.00194028665012365, 
-0.421806558423858, 2.32434581371786, 0.747010360297618, -0.0813744461748841, 
-0.875716041422489, -0.138113131549713, -0.89841151557242, -0.89841151557242, 
1.28035400282101, -0.887063778497454, -0.523936192098549, 0.588142041248097, 
0.792401308597481, 0.190971243624295, -0.89841151557242, 0.213666717774226, 
0.406578248048644, -0.887063778497454, 0.349839562673815, 4.04920184911266, 
-0.138113131549713, -0.887063778497454, -0.569327140398413, 2.50590960691731, 
2.77825529671649, 0.190971243624295, 1.51865648139529, -0.228895028149439, 
0.372535036823747, -0.909759252647386, -0.909759252647386, -0.887063778497454, 
0.41792598512361, -0.138113131549713, -0.444502032573789, 0.179623506549329, 
1.37113589942074, -0.68280451114807, 1.87043633071923, -0.671456774073105, 
-0.535283929173515, -0.909759252647386, 0.179623506549329, -0.887063778497454, 
1.53000421847026, -0.296981450599234, -0.592022614548344, 0.803749045672447, 
-0.909759252647386, 1.8477408565693, 0.588142041248097, -0.750890933597865, 
-0.796281881897728, -0.875716041422489, -0.909759252647386, -0.909759252647386, 
0.213666717774226, -0.909759252647386, -0.89841151557242, -0.569327140398413, 
-0.149460868624679, -0.353720135974063, -0.909759252647386, 1.22361531744618, 
0.372535036823747, -0.853020567272557, -0.716847722372968, -0.909759252647386, 
-0.887063778497454, -0.909759252647386, -0.853020567272557, 0.0774938728746368, 
-0.0246357608000552, 0.41792598512361, -0.89841151557242, -0.864368304347523, 
1.3484404252708, -0.115417657399781, -0.739543196522899, -0.89841151557242, 
-0.206199553999508, 0.259057666074089, -0.478545243798686, 0.406578248048644, 
0.894530942272173, 1.18957210622128, 1.51865648139529, -0.160808605699645, 
-0.444502032573789, -0.739543196522899, 1.64348158921991, 0.463316933423473, 
2.77825529671649, -0.89841151557242, 1.40517911064563, 2.65343018889187, 
1.58674290384509, -0.716847722372968, -0.909759252647386, -0.489892980873652, 
-0.864368304347523, -0.909759252647386, 0.565446567098165, -0.637413562848207, 
-0.887063778497454, -0.784934144822762, 2.40377997324262, -0.342372398899097, 
-0.796281881897728, -0.909759252647386, -0.0586789720249525, 
0.860487731047276, 0.259057666074089, -0.773586407747797, 1.09879020962156, 
-0.89841151557242, -0.240242765224405, 0.213666717774226, -0.523936192098549, 
-0.750890933597865, 2.00660917561882, -0.614718088698276, -0.909759252647386, 
-0.89841151557242, -0.68280451114807, 0.84913999397231, -0.887063778497454, 
-0.671456774073105, -0.115417657399781, -0.455849769648755, -0.81897735604766, 
1.76830669704454, 0.610837515398028, 0.508707881723336, -0.853020567272557, 
0.871835468122241, -0.523936192098549, 0.225014454849192, -0.716847722372968, 
0.213666717774226, -0.89841151557242, -0.909759252647386, -0.705499985298002, 
-0.716847722372968, -0.61320221823091, 0.0533700974209474, -0.44970334835404, 
3.29819382266961, -0.0598214278784247, -0.0598214278784247, 2.15370173353152, 
-0.487433856787164, 2.04051020823215, 1.77639664920028, -0.562894873653412, 
0.0156395889878234, -0.537741201364662, -0.61320221823091, -0.173012953177797, 
-0.0975519363115487, 2.04051020823215, -0.525164365220288, -0.462280184498414, 
-0.562894873653412, -0.525164365220288, -0.525164365220288, -0.185589789322171, 
-0.42454967606529, -0.61320221823091, 0.556443543195934, -0.537741201364662, 
-0.61320221823091, -0.537741201364662, -0.42454967606529, -0.61320221823091, 
-0.575471709797786, 0.631904560062183, -0.61320221823091, -0.61320221823091, 
1.53743676245716, -0.525164365220288, -0.588048545942161, -0.61320221823091, 
-0.512587529075913, 0.304906820308441, -0.487433856787164, 2.56873732629588, 
-0.562894873653412, 0.795403429939053, 1.05951698897092, -0.61320221823091, 
-0.61320221823091, 2.87058139376088, -0.588048545942161, -0.298781314621544, 
-0.512587529075913, -0.588048545942161, -0.61320221823091, -0.600625382086536, 
2.30462376726401, -0.588048545942161, 0.116254278142821, -0.600625382086536, 
-0.61320221823091, 0.594174051629059, 4.02765031904335, 0.116254278142821, 
-0.61320221823091, 1.24816953113654, 1.57516727089028, -0.500010692931538, 
2.11597122509839, -0.273627642332794, -0.600625382086536, -0.600625382086536, 
-0.361665495343417, -0.61320221823091, -0.61320221823091, -0.600625382086536, 
1.70093563233403, 0.35521416488594, -0.61320221823091, -0.600625382086536, 
-0.61320221823091, -0.600625382086536, 1.44939890944654, -0.512587529075913, 
2.35493111184151, -0.512587529075913, -0.42454967606529, -0.61320221823091, 
-0.474857020642789, -0.600625382086536, -0.61320221823091, -0.61320221823091, 
-0.550318037509037, 0.9211717913828, 0.153984786575945, -0.23589713389967, 
-0.61320221823091, -0.600625382086536, -0.61320221823091, 0.0785237697096968, 
2.78254354075025, -0.575471709797786, -0.61320221823091, -0.575471709797786, 
-0.61320221823091, -0.61320221823091, 0.883441282949676, -0.61320221823091, 
-0.600625382086536, -0.399396003776541, -0.562894873653412, -0.399396003776541, 
-0.61320221823091, -0.525164365220288, 0.984055972104674, -0.500010692931538, 
-0.562894873653412, -0.575471709797786, -0.61320221823091, -0.525164365220288, 
-0.588048545942161, 1.7638198130559, 1.57516727089028, -0.61320221823091, 
-0.61320221823091, -0.600625382086536, -0.537741201364662, 0.996632808249048, 
-0.61320221823091, -0.600625382086536, -0.336511823054668, -0.399396003776541, 
-0.61320221823091, 0.304906820308441, -0.361665495343417, -0.61320221823091, 
0.0785237697096968, 3.63776839856773, -0.537741201364662, -0.512587529075913, 
-0.399396003776541, 1.47455258173529, 0.292329984164066, -0.600625382086536, 
-0.223320297755295, 0.267176311875317, -0.487433856787164, -0.323934986910293, 
-0.61320221823091, 1.13497800583717, -0.61320221823091, -0.537741201364662, 
0.971479135960299, 0.0156395889878234, -0.600625382086536, -0.487433856787164, 
0.833133938372178, 2.84542772147213, -0.61320221823091, -0.61320221823091, 
0.392944673319064, 0.782826593794679, -0.61320221823091, -0.588048545942161, 
-0.537741201364662, -0.600625382086536, 1.7135124684784, 2.89573506604962, 
-0.42454967606529, -0.575471709797786, -0.61320221823091, 0.455828854040937, 
-0.575471709797786, -0.386819167632166, -0.562894873653412, -0.537741201364662, 
-0.374242331487792, -0.537741201364662, -0.223320297755295, -0.512587529075913, 
-0.575471709797786, -0.0598214278784247, -0.562894873653412, 
1.82670399377778, -0.61320221823091, 0.430675181752188, 2.14112489738714, 
-0.525164365220288, -0.487433856787164, -0.588048545942161, -0.61320221823091, 
-0.61320221823091, -0.575471709797786, -0.575471709797786, -1.04004516290537, 
0.0154246956882285, -1.12123515202795, 2.04517442375284, 0.28605799276351, 
0.0154246956882285, 0.935577905744186, -0.282271931094581, 1.50390782960228, 
1.31446452164958, -0.958855173782785, 0.394311311593623, -0.769411865830088, 
-1.04004516290537, 0.394311311593623, 2.5864410179034, 1.53097115930981, 
0.529627960131263, -1.01298183319784, -1.20242514115054, -0.282271931094581, 
-0.0657652934343561, 0.150741344225869, 0.637881278961376, -1.14829848173548, 
1.47684449989475, -0.146955282556941, 0.394311311593623, -0.228145271679525, 
-0.228145271679525, -0.715285206415032, 0.258994663055982, 0.908514576036657, 
-0.823538525245144, -1.20242514115054, 0.746134597791489, 0.0424880253957566, 
-0.174018612264469, -1.28361513027312, -0.850601854952673, 0.28605799276351, 
-0.119891952849412, 1.44978117018722, -0.174018612264469, 0.908514576036657, 
1.88279444550767, -1.04004516290537, -0.688221876707504, 1.50390782960228, 
-1.01298183319784, 0.475501300716207, 0.367247981886095, -0.174018612264469, 
-1.25655180056559, -0.715285206415032, 0.258994663055982, -1.17536181144301, 
1.26033786223452, -1.12123515202795, -0.769411865830088, 1.39565451077216, 
1.88279444550767, 1.09795788398935, -0.661158546999976, 0.150741344225869, 
1.74747779697003, -0.823538525245144, 0.935577905744186, 1.9098577752152, 
-0.715285206415032, -1.25655180056559, -0.634095217292447, 0.610817949253848, 
0.28605799276351, -0.498778568754807, 1.74747779697003, 0.475501300716207, 
-0.715285206415032, -1.28361513027312, -0.769411865830088, -1.25655180056559, 
1.77454112667756, -0.634095217292447, 0.448437971008679, -0.390525249924694, 
0.58375461954632, -1.17536181144301, 0.529627960131263, -0.823538525245144, 
-1.04004516290537, -1.04004516290537, -0.661158546999976, 0.367247981886095, 
1.53097115930981, -0.796475195537616, -0.552905228169863, -0.471715239047278, 
-1.04004516290537, 2.18049107229048, 1.77454112667756, -1.09417182232043, 
-0.904728514367729, -1.22948847085807, -1.04004516290537, -1.14829848173548, 
0.475501300716207, 1.39565451077216, -0.769411865830088, -0.607031887584919, 
0.177804673933397, -0.688221876707504, -1.04004516290537, 0.0154246956882285, 
0.0154246956882285, -1.17536181144301, -0.958855173782785, -1.28361513027312, 
0.529627960131263, -1.04004516290537, -1.25655180056559, 1.233274532527, 
1.20621120281947, -0.363461920217166, -1.28361513027312, 1.15208454340441, 
0.58375461954632, 0.502564630423735, -1.12123515202795, -1.22948847085807, 
0.556691289838792, 0.637881278961376, -0.904728514367729, 0.664944608668904, 
0.340184652178566, -0.0657652934343561, 1.63922447813992, 1.66628780784745, 
-1.0671084926129, 1.34152785135711, 0.394311311593623, 1.50390782960228, 
1.80160445638509, 0.529627960131263, 0.773197927499017, 1.42271784047969, 
0.394311311593623, -0.607031887584919, -0.769411865830088, -0.174018612264469, 
-1.28361513027312, -1.22948847085807, 1.28740119194205, -0.201081941971997, 
0.502564630423735, -0.904728514367729, 1.77454112667756, 1.55803448901733, 
-0.985918503490313, -1.04004516290537, 0.908514576036657, 1.39565451077216, 
-0.715285206415032, -0.850601854952673, 0.204868003640925, -0.0387019637268278, 
0.637881278961376, 1.44978117018722, -1.04004516290537, -1.22948847085807, 
0.421374641301151, -0.255208601387053, -1.28361513027312, -0.958855173782785, 
-1.01298183319784, 0.421374641301151, -0.958855173782785, -0.931791844075257, 
-0.715285206415032, -1.04004516290537, 0.935577905744186, 1.09795788398935, 
-0.552905228169863, 1.50390782960228, 0.231931333348454, 1.0438312245743, 
0.475501300716207, -0.661158546999976, -1.0671084926129, 0.773197927499017, 
-0.769411865830088, -1.28361513027312, -0.634095217292447, -0.0387019637268278
), .Dim = c(193L, 4L), .Dimnames = list(NULL, c("beer_servings", 
"spirit_servings", "wine_servings", "total_litres_of_pure_alcohol"
)), "`scaled:center`" = c(beer_servings = 106.284974093264, spirit_servings = 81.1709844559585, 
wine_servings = 49.7564766839378, total_litres_of_pure_alcohol = 4.84300518134715
), "`scaled:scale`" = c(beer_servings = 101.014265866079, spirit_servings = 88.1232966003502, 
wine_servings = 79.511252951107, total_litres_of_pure_alcohol = 3.69503682956585
))
```

Comment: Please share your data using `dput(df)`?

Comment: How can I show you the output? Is too long

Comment: Quinten I updated my question and put the output.

Comment: Ok thank you, but there arent any methods or suggestion that can help me to display the graph?

Comment: I get the same error using completely different data.

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem and it turned out that the function `fviz_nbclust` (and also the hidden function `.viz_NbClust` as a matter of fact) is written wrongly. Specifically, the problem is the tests `if (class(best_nc) == "numeric")` and `if (class(best_nc) == "matrix")` in the both functions which are nonsense as the object `best_nc`, which is the element of the NbClust result `nb$Best.nc`, has actually two classes:

```
> class(nb$Best.nc)
[1] "matrix" "array"
```

So, the tests will fail as `if` can take only one logical value as the condition, but the tests produce two values:

```
> class(nb$Best.nc) == "numeric"
[1] FALSE FALSE
> if(class(nb$Best.nc) == "numeric") something()
Error in if (class(nb$Best.nc) == "numeric") something() : 
  the condition has length > 1
```

**My solution:** I had to fix the functions `fviz_nbclust` and `.viz_NbClust` so that the tests look like `if (any(class(best_nc) == "numeric") )` and `if (any(class(best_nc) == "matrix") )`. Here is a working code:

```
library(factoextra)
library(NbClust)
# fix the functions
fviz_nbclust <- function (x, FUNcluster = NULL, method = c("silhouette", "wss", 
                                           "gap_stat"), diss = NULL, k.max = 10, nboot = 100, verbose = interactive(), 
          barfill = "steelblue", barcolor = "steelblue", linecolor = "steelblue", 
          print.summary = TRUE, ...) 
{
  set.seed(123)
  if (k.max < 2) 
    stop("k.max must bet > = 2")
  method = match.arg(method)
  if (!inherits(x, c("data.frame", "matrix")) & !("Best.nc" %in% 
                                                  names(x))) 
    stop("x should be an object of class matrix/data.frame or ", 
         "an object created by the function NbClust() [NbClust package].")
  if (inherits(x, "list") & "Best.nc" %in% names(x)) {
    best_nc <- x$Best.nc
    if (any(class(best_nc) == "numeric") ) 
      print(best_nc)
    else if (any(class(best_nc) == "matrix") )
      .viz_NbClust(x, print.summary, barfill, barcolor)
  }
  else if (is.null(FUNcluster)) 
    stop("The argument FUNcluster is required. ", "Possible values are kmeans, pam, hcut, clara, ...")
  else if (!is.function(FUNcluster)) {
    stop("The argument FUNcluster should be a function. ", 
         "Check if you're not overriding the specified function name somewhere.")
  }
  else if (method %in% c("silhouette", "wss")) {
    if (is.data.frame(x)) 
      x <- as.matrix(x)
    if (is.null(diss)) 
      diss <- stats::dist(x)
    v <- rep(0, k.max)
    if (method == "silhouette") {
      for (i in 2:k.max) {
        clust <- FUNcluster(x, i, ...)
        v[i] <- .get_ave_sil_width(diss, clust$cluster)
      }
    }
    else if (method == "wss") {
      for (i in 1:k.max) {
        clust <- FUNcluster(x, i, ...)
        v[i] <- .get_withinSS(diss, clust$cluster)
      }
    }
    df <- data.frame(clusters = as.factor(1:k.max), y = v, 
                     stringsAsFactors = TRUE)
    ylab <- "Total Within Sum of Square"
    if (method == "silhouette") 
      ylab <- "Average silhouette width"
    p <- ggpubr::ggline(df, x = "clusters", y = "y", group = 1, 
                        color = linecolor, ylab = ylab, xlab = "Number of clusters k", 
                        main = "Optimal number of clusters")
    if (method == "silhouette") 
      p <- p + geom_vline(xintercept = which.max(v), linetype = 2, 
                          color = linecolor)
    return(p)
  }
  else if (method == "gap_stat") {
    extra_args <- list(...)
    gap_stat <- cluster::clusGap(x, FUNcluster, K.max = k.max, 
                                 B = nboot, verbose = verbose, ...)
    if (!is.null(extra_args$maxSE)) 
      maxSE <- extra_args$maxSE
    else maxSE <- list(method = "firstSEmax", SE.factor = 1)
    p <- fviz_gap_stat(gap_stat, linecolor = linecolor, 
                       maxSE = maxSE)
    return(p)
  }
}

.viz_NbClust <- function (x, print.summary = TRUE, barfill = "steelblue", 
          barcolor = "steelblue") 
{
  best_nc <- x$Best.nc
  if (any(class(best_nc) == "numeric") )
    print(best_nc)
  else if (any(class(best_nc) == "matrix") ) {
    best_nc <- as.data.frame(t(best_nc), stringsAsFactors = TRUE)
    best_nc$Number_clusters <- as.factor(best_nc$Number_clusters)
    if (print.summary) {
      ss <- summary(best_nc$Number_clusters)
      cat("Among all indices: \n===================\n")
      for (i in 1:length(ss)) {
        cat("*", ss[i], "proposed ", names(ss)[i], 
            "as the best number of clusters\n")
      }
      cat("\nConclusion\n=========================\n")
      cat("* According to the majority rule, the best number of clusters is ", 
          names(which.max(ss)), ".\n\n")
    }
    df <- data.frame(Number_clusters = names(ss), freq = ss, 
                     stringsAsFactors = TRUE)
    p <- ggpubr::ggbarplot(df, x = "Number_clusters", 
                           y = "freq", fill = barfill, color = barcolor) + 
      labs(x = "Number of clusters k", y = "Frequency among all indices", 
           title = paste0("Optimal number of clusters - k = ", 
                          names(which.max(ss))))
    return(p)
  }
}
# assign them to the factoextra namespace
environment(fviz_nbclust) <- asNamespace("factoextra")
assignInNamespace("fviz_nbclust",fviz_nbclust,"factoextra")
environment(.viz_NbClust) <- asNamespace("factoextra")
assignInNamespace(".viz_NbClust",.viz_NbClust,"factoextra")
# test it
# your data
df <- structure(c(-1.04227826822844, -0.171114188130418, -0.804688064565345, 
                  1.37322213567972, 1.09603356473944, -0.042419494479573, 0.85844336107634, 
                  -0.844286431842528, 1.53161560478845, 1.70980825753577, -0.844286431842528, 
                  0.155572341906342, -0.636395003637318, -1.04227826822844, 0.363463770111553, 
                  0.353564178292257, 1.86820172664451, 1.55141478842704, -0.715591738191684, 
                  -0.824487248203937, 0.60105397377465, -0.299808881781262, 0.660451524690425, 
                  1.37322213567972, -0.745290513649571, 1.23462785020958, -0.804688064565345, 
                  -0.181013779949713, -0.685892962733796, 0.373363361930848, -0.487901126347882, 
                  0.403062137388736, 1.32372417658324, -0.883884799119711, -0.903683982758303, 
                  0.234769076460708, -0.270110106323375, 0.521857239220284, -1.04227826822844, 
                  -0.299808881781262, -0.963081533674077, 0.422861321027327, 1.22472825839028, 
                  -0.131515820853235, 0.848543769257044, 2.52157478671803, -1.04227826822844, 
                  -0.735390921830275, 1.16533070747451, -0.903683982758303, -0.53739908544436, 
                  0.85844336107634, 0.551556014678172, -0.992780309131965, -0.53739908544436, 
                  -0.14141541267253, -0.873985207300416, 1.16533070747451, -0.854186023661824, 
                  -0.289909289961967, 1.55141478842704, 0.205070301002821, 2.38298050124788, 
                  -0.972981125493373, -0.53739908544436, 2.37308090942859, -0.745290513649571, 
                  0.264467851918595, 0.917840911992114, -0.527499493625065, -0.963081533674077, 
                  -0.774989289107458, -0.131515820853235, -1.04227826822844, -0.369106024516333, 
                  1.26432662566747, 1.25442703384817, -0.963081533674077, -1.00267990095126, 
                  -1.04227826822844, -0.963081533674077, 2.04639437939183, -0.428503575432107, 
                  -0.210712555407601, -0.240411330865488, -0.289909289961967, -0.992780309131965, 
                  0.175371525544933, -0.478001534528586, -0.844286431842528, -1.04227826822844, 
                  -0.745290513649571, -0.438403167251403, 1.72960744117437, -0.854186023661824, 
                  -0.240411330865488, -0.86408561548112, -1.04227826822844, 2.3433821339707, 
                  1.28412580930606, -0.79478847274605, -0.972981125493373, -0.923483166396894, 
                  -1.04227826822844, -1.00267990095126, 0.422861321027327, -1.04227826822844, 
                  -1.04227826822844, -0.082017861756756, 1.30392499294465, -0.438403167251403, 
                  -1.04227826822844, -0.289909289961967, -0.745290513649571, -0.93338275821619, 
                  -0.586897044540839, -1.00267990095126, 2.67006866400746, -0.567097860902248, 
                  -1.00267990095126, 1.43261968659549, 0.957439279269297, -0.280009698142671, 
                  -1.02247908458985, -0.636395003637318, 0.808945401979861, 0.620853157413242, 
                  -0.834386840023233, -1.03237867640915, 1.97709723665676, 1.76920580845155, 
                  -0.616595819998726, 1.05643519746225, 0.561455606497468, -0.349306840877741, 
                  2.3433821339707, 0.868342952895636, -1.04227826822844, 0.333764994653665, 
                  0.0268776482554972, 1.8880009102831, 1.39302131931831, -0.626495411818022, 
                  0.868342952895636, 0.640652341051833, 0.13577315826775, -0.0127207190216858, 
                  -1.04227826822844, -0.497800718167177, -1.04227826822844, -0.963081533674077, 
                  1.74940662481296, 0.502058055581693, -0.804688064565345, -0.458202350889994, 
                  0.888142136534227, 1.62071193116211, -0.497800718167177, -1.04227826822844, 
                  1.1752302992938, 1.75930621663225, -0.893784390939007, -0.972981125493373, 
                  0.214969892822116, -0.161214596311122, 0.452560096485214, 0.779246626521974, 
                  -1.00267990095126, -1.03237867640915, -0.0721182699374602, -0.00282112720239002, 
                  -1.04227826822844, -0.695792554553092, -0.695792554553092, 0.898041728353523, 
                  -0.547298677263656, -0.547298677263656, -0.86408561548112, -0.992780309131965, 
                  -0.60669622817943, 0.987138054727185, -0.893784390939007, 1.11583274837803, 
                  -0.695792554553092, 1.4128205029569, 0.0862751991712717, -0.804688064565345, 
                  -0.844286431842528, 2.24438621577774, 0.0466768318940887, -0.992780309131965, 
                  -0.735390921830275, -0.418603983612811, -0.909759252647386, 0.576794304173131, 
                  -0.89841151557242, 0.644880726622926, -0.274285976449302, 0.531403355873268, 
                  -0.637413562848207, 1.11013794669652, -0.104069920324816, -0.0700267090999183, 
                  -0.399111084273926, 1.07609473547163, -0.206199553999508, -0.909759252647386, 
                  1.04205152424673, 3.31159893923988, 0.0321029245747737, 0.372535036823747, 
                  -0.875716041422489, -0.89841151557242, -0.455849769648755, 1.04205152424673, 
                  -0.523936192098549, 0.724314886147686, -0.89841151557242, 1.93852275316902, 
                  -0.841672830197591, -0.909759252647386, -0.909759252647386, -0.285633713524268, 
                  -0.183504079849576, -0.909759252647386, 0.463316933423473, -0.89841151557242, 
                  -0.909759252647386, 0.486012407573405, 1.25765852867108, -0.0586789720249525, 
                  -0.887063778497454, -0.909759252647386, 1.96121822731896, 0.066146135799671, 
                  0.066146135799671, 0.63353298954796, 0.826444519822378, 1.00800831302183, 
                  -0.909759252647386, -0.887063778497454, -0.00194028665012365, 
                  -0.421806558423858, 2.32434581371786, 0.747010360297618, -0.0813744461748841, 
                  -0.875716041422489, -0.138113131549713, -0.89841151557242, -0.89841151557242, 
                  1.28035400282101, -0.887063778497454, -0.523936192098549, 0.588142041248097, 
                  0.792401308597481, 0.190971243624295, -0.89841151557242, 0.213666717774226, 
                  0.406578248048644, -0.887063778497454, 0.349839562673815, 4.04920184911266, 
                  -0.138113131549713, -0.887063778497454, -0.569327140398413, 2.50590960691731, 
                  2.77825529671649, 0.190971243624295, 1.51865648139529, -0.228895028149439, 
                  0.372535036823747, -0.909759252647386, -0.909759252647386, -0.887063778497454, 
                  0.41792598512361, -0.138113131549713, -0.444502032573789, 0.179623506549329, 
                  1.37113589942074, -0.68280451114807, 1.87043633071923, -0.671456774073105, 
                  -0.535283929173515, -0.909759252647386, 0.179623506549329, -0.887063778497454, 
                  1.53000421847026, -0.296981450599234, -0.592022614548344, 0.803749045672447, 
                  -0.909759252647386, 1.8477408565693, 0.588142041248097, -0.750890933597865, 
                  -0.796281881897728, -0.875716041422489, -0.909759252647386, -0.909759252647386, 
                  0.213666717774226, -0.909759252647386, -0.89841151557242, -0.569327140398413, 
                  -0.149460868624679, -0.353720135974063, -0.909759252647386, 1.22361531744618, 
                  0.372535036823747, -0.853020567272557, -0.716847722372968, -0.909759252647386, 
                  -0.887063778497454, -0.909759252647386, -0.853020567272557, 0.0774938728746368, 
                  -0.0246357608000552, 0.41792598512361, -0.89841151557242, -0.864368304347523, 
                  1.3484404252708, -0.115417657399781, -0.739543196522899, -0.89841151557242, 
                  -0.206199553999508, 0.259057666074089, -0.478545243798686, 0.406578248048644, 
                  0.894530942272173, 1.18957210622128, 1.51865648139529, -0.160808605699645, 
                  -0.444502032573789, -0.739543196522899, 1.64348158921991, 0.463316933423473, 
                  2.77825529671649, -0.89841151557242, 1.40517911064563, 2.65343018889187, 
                  1.58674290384509, -0.716847722372968, -0.909759252647386, -0.489892980873652, 
                  -0.864368304347523, -0.909759252647386, 0.565446567098165, -0.637413562848207, 
                  -0.887063778497454, -0.784934144822762, 2.40377997324262, -0.342372398899097, 
                  -0.796281881897728, -0.909759252647386, -0.0586789720249525, 
                  0.860487731047276, 0.259057666074089, -0.773586407747797, 1.09879020962156, 
                  -0.89841151557242, -0.240242765224405, 0.213666717774226, -0.523936192098549, 
                  -0.750890933597865, 2.00660917561882, -0.614718088698276, -0.909759252647386, 
                  -0.89841151557242, -0.68280451114807, 0.84913999397231, -0.887063778497454, 
                  -0.671456774073105, -0.115417657399781, -0.455849769648755, -0.81897735604766, 
                  1.76830669704454, 0.610837515398028, 0.508707881723336, -0.853020567272557, 
                  0.871835468122241, -0.523936192098549, 0.225014454849192, -0.716847722372968, 
                  0.213666717774226, -0.89841151557242, -0.909759252647386, -0.705499985298002, 
                  -0.716847722372968, -0.61320221823091, 0.0533700974209474, -0.44970334835404, 
                  3.29819382266961, -0.0598214278784247, -0.0598214278784247, 2.15370173353152, 
                  -0.487433856787164, 2.04051020823215, 1.77639664920028, -0.562894873653412, 
                  0.0156395889878234, -0.537741201364662, -0.61320221823091, -0.173012953177797, 
                  -0.0975519363115487, 2.04051020823215, -0.525164365220288, -0.462280184498414, 
                  -0.562894873653412, -0.525164365220288, -0.525164365220288, -0.185589789322171, 
                  -0.42454967606529, -0.61320221823091, 0.556443543195934, -0.537741201364662, 
                  -0.61320221823091, -0.537741201364662, -0.42454967606529, -0.61320221823091, 
                  -0.575471709797786, 0.631904560062183, -0.61320221823091, -0.61320221823091, 
                  1.53743676245716, -0.525164365220288, -0.588048545942161, -0.61320221823091, 
                  -0.512587529075913, 0.304906820308441, -0.487433856787164, 2.56873732629588, 
                  -0.562894873653412, 0.795403429939053, 1.05951698897092, -0.61320221823091, 
                  -0.61320221823091, 2.87058139376088, -0.588048545942161, -0.298781314621544, 
                  -0.512587529075913, -0.588048545942161, -0.61320221823091, -0.600625382086536, 
                  2.30462376726401, -0.588048545942161, 0.116254278142821, -0.600625382086536, 
                  -0.61320221823091, 0.594174051629059, 4.02765031904335, 0.116254278142821, 
                  -0.61320221823091, 1.24816953113654, 1.57516727089028, -0.500010692931538, 
                  2.11597122509839, -0.273627642332794, -0.600625382086536, -0.600625382086536, 
                  -0.361665495343417, -0.61320221823091, -0.61320221823091, -0.600625382086536, 
                  1.70093563233403, 0.35521416488594, -0.61320221823091, -0.600625382086536, 
                  -0.61320221823091, -0.600625382086536, 1.44939890944654, -0.512587529075913, 
                  2.35493111184151, -0.512587529075913, -0.42454967606529, -0.61320221823091, 
                  -0.474857020642789, -0.600625382086536, -0.61320221823091, -0.61320221823091, 
                  -0.550318037509037, 0.9211717913828, 0.153984786575945, -0.23589713389967, 
                  -0.61320221823091, -0.600625382086536, -0.61320221823091, 0.0785237697096968, 
                  2.78254354075025, -0.575471709797786, -0.61320221823091, -0.575471709797786, 
                  -0.61320221823091, -0.61320221823091, 0.883441282949676, -0.61320221823091, 
                  -0.600625382086536, -0.399396003776541, -0.562894873653412, -0.399396003776541, 
                  -0.61320221823091, -0.525164365220288, 0.984055972104674, -0.500010692931538, 
                  -0.562894873653412, -0.575471709797786, -0.61320221823091, -0.525164365220288, 
                  -0.588048545942161, 1.7638198130559, 1.57516727089028, -0.61320221823091, 
                  -0.61320221823091, -0.600625382086536, -0.537741201364662, 0.996632808249048, 
                  -0.61320221823091, -0.600625382086536, -0.336511823054668, -0.399396003776541, 
                  -0.61320221823091, 0.304906820308441, -0.361665495343417, -0.61320221823091, 
                  0.0785237697096968, 3.63776839856773, -0.537741201364662, -0.512587529075913, 
                  -0.399396003776541, 1.47455258173529, 0.292329984164066, -0.600625382086536, 
                  -0.223320297755295, 0.267176311875317, -0.487433856787164, -0.323934986910293, 
                  -0.61320221823091, 1.13497800583717, -0.61320221823091, -0.537741201364662, 
                  0.971479135960299, 0.0156395889878234, -0.600625382086536, -0.487433856787164, 
                  0.833133938372178, 2.84542772147213, -0.61320221823091, -0.61320221823091, 
                  0.392944673319064, 0.782826593794679, -0.61320221823091, -0.588048545942161, 
                  -0.537741201364662, -0.600625382086536, 1.7135124684784, 2.89573506604962, 
                  -0.42454967606529, -0.575471709797786, -0.61320221823091, 0.455828854040937, 
                  -0.575471709797786, -0.386819167632166, -0.562894873653412, -0.537741201364662, 
                  -0.374242331487792, -0.537741201364662, -0.223320297755295, -0.512587529075913, 
                  -0.575471709797786, -0.0598214278784247, -0.562894873653412, 
                  1.82670399377778, -0.61320221823091, 0.430675181752188, 2.14112489738714, 
                  -0.525164365220288, -0.487433856787164, -0.588048545942161, -0.61320221823091, 
                  -0.61320221823091, -0.575471709797786, -0.575471709797786, -1.04004516290537, 
                  0.0154246956882285, -1.12123515202795, 2.04517442375284, 0.28605799276351, 
                  0.0154246956882285, 0.935577905744186, -0.282271931094581, 1.50390782960228, 
                  1.31446452164958, -0.958855173782785, 0.394311311593623, -0.769411865830088, 
                  -1.04004516290537, 0.394311311593623, 2.5864410179034, 1.53097115930981, 
                  0.529627960131263, -1.01298183319784, -1.20242514115054, -0.282271931094581, 
                  -0.0657652934343561, 0.150741344225869, 0.637881278961376, -1.14829848173548, 
                  1.47684449989475, -0.146955282556941, 0.394311311593623, -0.228145271679525, 
                  -0.228145271679525, -0.715285206415032, 0.258994663055982, 0.908514576036657, 
                  -0.823538525245144, -1.20242514115054, 0.746134597791489, 0.0424880253957566, 
                  -0.174018612264469, -1.28361513027312, -0.850601854952673, 0.28605799276351, 
                  -0.119891952849412, 1.44978117018722, -0.174018612264469, 0.908514576036657, 
                  1.88279444550767, -1.04004516290537, -0.688221876707504, 1.50390782960228, 
                  -1.01298183319784, 0.475501300716207, 0.367247981886095, -0.174018612264469, 
                  -1.25655180056559, -0.715285206415032, 0.258994663055982, -1.17536181144301, 
                  1.26033786223452, -1.12123515202795, -0.769411865830088, 1.39565451077216, 
                  1.88279444550767, 1.09795788398935, -0.661158546999976, 0.150741344225869, 
                  1.74747779697003, -0.823538525245144, 0.935577905744186, 1.9098577752152, 
                  -0.715285206415032, -1.25655180056559, -0.634095217292447, 0.610817949253848, 
                  0.28605799276351, -0.498778568754807, 1.74747779697003, 0.475501300716207, 
                  -0.715285206415032, -1.28361513027312, -0.769411865830088, -1.25655180056559, 
                  1.77454112667756, -0.634095217292447, 0.448437971008679, -0.390525249924694, 
                  0.58375461954632, -1.17536181144301, 0.529627960131263, -0.823538525245144, 
                  -1.04004516290537, -1.04004516290537, -0.661158546999976, 0.367247981886095, 
                  1.53097115930981, -0.796475195537616, -0.552905228169863, -0.471715239047278, 
                  -1.04004516290537, 2.18049107229048, 1.77454112667756, -1.09417182232043, 
                  -0.904728514367729, -1.22948847085807, -1.04004516290537, -1.14829848173548, 
                  0.475501300716207, 1.39565451077216, -0.769411865830088, -0.607031887584919, 
                  0.177804673933397, -0.688221876707504, -1.04004516290537, 0.0154246956882285, 
                  0.0154246956882285, -1.17536181144301, -0.958855173782785, -1.28361513027312, 
                  0.529627960131263, -1.04004516290537, -1.25655180056559, 1.233274532527, 
                  1.20621120281947, -0.363461920217166, -1.28361513027312, 1.15208454340441, 
                  0.58375461954632, 0.502564630423735, -1.12123515202795, -1.22948847085807, 
                  0.556691289838792, 0.637881278961376, -0.904728514367729, 0.664944608668904, 
                  0.340184652178566, -0.0657652934343561, 1.63922447813992, 1.66628780784745, 
                  -1.0671084926129, 1.34152785135711, 0.394311311593623, 1.50390782960228, 
                  1.80160445638509, 0.529627960131263, 0.773197927499017, 1.42271784047969, 
                  0.394311311593623, -0.607031887584919, -0.769411865830088, -0.174018612264469, 
                  -1.28361513027312, -1.22948847085807, 1.28740119194205, -0.201081941971997, 
                  0.502564630423735, -0.904728514367729, 1.77454112667756, 1.55803448901733, 
                  -0.985918503490313, -1.04004516290537, 0.908514576036657, 1.39565451077216, 
                  -0.715285206415032, -0.850601854952673, 0.204868003640925, -0.0387019637268278, 
                  0.637881278961376, 1.44978117018722, -1.04004516290537, -1.22948847085807, 
                  0.421374641301151, -0.255208601387053, -1.28361513027312, -0.958855173782785, 
                  -1.01298183319784, 0.421374641301151, -0.958855173782785, -0.931791844075257, 
                  -0.715285206415032, -1.04004516290537, 0.935577905744186, 1.09795788398935, 
                  -0.552905228169863, 1.50390782960228, 0.231931333348454, 1.0438312245743, 
                  0.475501300716207, -0.661158546999976, -1.0671084926129, 0.773197927499017, 
                  -0.769411865830088, -1.28361513027312, -0.634095217292447, -0.0387019637268278
), .Dim = c(193L, 4L), .Dimnames = list(NULL, c("beer_servings", 
                                                "spirit_servings", "wine_servings", "total_litres_of_pure_alcohol"
)), "`scaled:center`" = c(beer_servings = 106.284974093264, spirit_servings = 81.1709844559585, 
                          wine_servings = 49.7564766839378, total_litres_of_pure_alcohol = 4.84300518134715
), "`scaled:scale`" = c(beer_servings = 101.014265866079, spirit_servings = 88.1232966003502, 
                        wine_servings = 79.511252951107, total_litres_of_pure_alcohol = 3.69503682956585
))
# run NbClust
nb<-NbClust(df, diss=NULL,distance="euclidean",method="average")
# run the corrected version of fviz_nbclust
fviz_nbclust(nb)
```

Result: [image: Output of the corrected fviz_nbclust function]